# Where is trace_netif_rx_entry function defined in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming

in linux kernel source codes, net/core/dev.c, the function netif_rx() calls trace_netif_rx_entry():

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    trace_netif_rx_entry(skb);
    return netif_rx_internal(skb);
}
```

However, I searched via grep and could not find the definition of trace_netif_rx_entry in the source codes. Then I googled still no answer. Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

I know the reason: a trick named [Linux trace point](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/tracepoints.txt)